# Azure WebJob concurrency when using ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, servicebus, azure-webjobssdk

I have been using Azure Storage Queues to feed a WebJob, using the `QueueTrigger` attribute. I configure my `QueueTrigger` to dequeue a number of items for concurrent processing, like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    config.NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver();

    config.Queues.NewBatchThreshold = 10;

    JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}

public static void ExecuteStorageQueueItem([QueueTrigger("%AzureQueueName%")] CloudQueueMessage message, TextWriter logger)
{
    ProcessRequest(message.AsString, logger);
}
```

I would prefer to use Service Bus. Does the `MaxConcurrentCalls` parameter on `ServiceBusConfiguration` allow for the same automatic parallel execution? For example:

```
public static void Main()
{

    JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    config.NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver();

    ServiceBusConfiguration serviceBusConfig = new ServiceBusConfiguration();
    serviceBusConfig.MessageOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 10;
    config.UseServiceBus(serviceBusConfig);

    JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}

public static void ExecuteServiceBusItem([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusQueueName%")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter logger)
{
    ProcessRequest(message.GetBody<string>(), logger);            
}
```

I'm not sure whether `MaxConcurrentCalls` does what I think it does!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially yes, `MaxConcurrentCalls` defines the amount of threads used by the Client to process the queue.

When `QueueClient.OnMessage` method is called [it starts a message pump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.onmessage.aspx) on an infinte loop that is constantly polling. The `OnMessageOptions.MaxConcurrentCall` sets the [number of concurrent calls to the callback the message pump should initiate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions.maxconcurrentcalls.aspx).

More back story: [Introducing the Event-Driven Message Programming Model for the Windows Azure Service Bus](http://fabriccontroller.net/introducing-the-event-driven-message-programming-model-for-the-windows-azure-service-bus/)

Comment: I am still not totally sure about the WebJob scenario. Do the "concurrent calls to the callback" translate directly to concurrent calls to the method marked `ServiceBusTrigger`?

Comment: I've just finished setting up this scenario and I can confirm that it works :-)